# How to correctly read JSON on iOS

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to read a JSON what I am getting from a POST request. The problem is, that I can't get nested Dictionaries. I tried to save the json and then use the file on my mac and everything works! I am using this methode to get the JSON from the server:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (!connectionError) {
            if (![[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] isEqualToString:@"{\"response\":{\"status\":\"fail\",\"message\":\"Please use a POST request.\",\"code\":4012}}"]) {
                NSError *error;
                NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/David/Downloads/Test"] options:kNilOptions error:&error]; //This returns a other JSON than the JSON stored on my mac
                NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"list"];
                NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
                for (NSInteger i = 0; array.count>i; i++) {
                    NSDictionary *listDictionary = [array objectAtIndex:i];
                    NSDictionary *defenition = [listDictionary objectForKey:@"definition"];
                    [mutableDict setObject:[defenition objectForKey:@"form"] forKey:[listDictionary objectForKey:@"term"]];
                }
                NSLog(@"%@",  mutableDict);
            }
        }
    }];
```

Now the question, must I use another methode to get the correct JSON from a NSURLConnection?

Thanks

***EDIT***

This is the json I downloaded and what I have on my mac:

```
{
  "response" : {
    "status" : "success",
    "code" : "200",
    "message" : "OK"
  },
  "list" : [
    {
      "term" : "Black",
      "context" : "",
      "created" : "2014-04-17 20:34:33",
      "updated" : "",
      "definition" : {
        "form" : "Schwarz",
        "fuzzy" : 0,
        "updated" : "2014-04-17 21:35:50"
      },
      "reference" : "",
      "tags" : []
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I get from the dictionary "dict":

```
{
  "response" : {
    "status" : "success",
    "code" : "200",
    "message" : "OK"
  },
  "list" : [
    {
      "term" : "Black",
      "context" : "",
      "created" : "2014-04-17 20:34:33",
      "updated" : "",
      "reference" : "",
      "tags" : []
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice, that the dictionary "definition" is missing!

Comment: Why are you reading the JSON from a file rather than using the data received over the net (which presumably would be in an NSData object)?

Comment: And why are you using that funky string compare to check for a failure?

Comment: You're getting a different value **BECAUSE YOU'RE READING FROM A FILE**.

Comment: (Which version is stored in "/Users/David/Downloads/Test"?)

Answer (score 2):

If you can limit your app to iOS 5.0+ then go for `NSJSONSerialization`. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html

If you really need to support older iOS versions then get back to me and I'll dig for the the framwork that was common those dark days. (I just don't recall its name by hard)

Comment: Let me translate the first sentence for you. "Limit your app to ios 5+". Tbh you should even be thinking about limiting to 7+ by now anyway.

Comment: @Fogmeister, why? NSJSONSerialization was introduced with iOS 5. Are there any significant improvmeents regarding NSJOSNSerialization sice then? There are sometimes good reasons out there for backward compatibility. Especially when your customers are not disciples of Apple and think, that their 3 years old stock of probalbly thousands of hardware devices in their enterprise should not become obsolent just because of an additional app. The point is that I did not recommend an outdated framwork because iOS 5 is reasonably ols but if David needs it, I am still happy to help.

Comment: I don't get the whole point of this "answer".  The OP was already using NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: H, the application I am making is only for iOS 7, so I can use NSJSONSerialization…

Comment: @HotLicks, right. He was using it already, which I must have overlooked.

Comment: @HermannKlecker for me it's all about the numbers and the availability of new and more convenient APIs. At the last update 7 was at 87% and 6 at 11%. I'd rather give the 87% an amazing experience than tarnish the experience for them in favour of the (shrinking) 13% of the other users. Or even just increasing the dev time by conditionally using old APIs depending on iOS version.

Comment: @Fogmeister if you have the freedom of doing so, that is fine. If somebody only creates apps for the free market, that may be wise or at least reasonable. But sometimes we face other constraints. However, David was using NSJSONSerialization anyway, which I overlooked. Therefore there is not really a point in my answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess (I always have to dig through the docs to figure out com protocols):

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (!connectionError) {
        if (![[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] isEqualToString:@"{\"response\":{\"status\":\"fail\",\"message\":\"Please use a POST request.\",\"code\":4012}}"]) {  // This test is bogus but we'll leave it for now
            NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            if (dict == nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error deserializing JSON: %@", error);
                // Do something
            }
            if (![dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                NSLog(@"Did not receive dictionary as outer JSON: %@", dict);
                // Do something
            }
            NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"list"];
            NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
            for (NSInteger i = 0; array.count>i; i++) {
                NSDictionary *listDictionary = [array objectAtIndex:i];
                NSDictionary *defenition = [listDictionary objectForKey:@"definition"];
                [mutableDict setObject:[defenition objectForKey:@"form"] forKey:[listDictionary objectForKey:@"term"]];
            }
            NSLog(@"%@",  mutableDict);
        }
        else {
            // Do something
        }
    }
    else {
        // Do something
    }
}];
```

Comment: Hi, I can get the NSDictionary, and I know the structure. I am using Cocoa JSON Editor on my mac. I edited the answer with an example JSON file

Comment: @DavidG. - The two different versions of JSON are exactly that -- **different** versions.  If you get one instead of the other it's because you have **different** data -- has nothing to do with parsing the JSON.

Comment: You are right, I forgot one parameter in the POST request. Shame on me! So I got 2 different JSONS

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `NSURLConnection` unless you need to send custom HTTP headers or something. Instead use `NSData`'s own ability to load from a URL, it will get all the HTTP headers and performance stuff and error checking right if you just want a basic URL request. My sample code shows how to do this, and also shows how to use `NSURLConnection` properly with custom post data/etc (commented out).

Also, do not use `sendAsynchronousRequest:` in this case. Instead create your own asynchronous block of code so that you can send the URL request *and also decode the JSON* on a background thread. Drop back to the main thread when you actually want to use the decoded data.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

  // basic get request:
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  if (!data) {
    NSLog(@"http error");
    return;
  }

  // more complex get or post request, where you need to send parameters or custom headers or caching
  //NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
  //[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  //[request setHTTPBody:postData];
  //NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
  //NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:NULL];
  //if (!data || [urlResponse statusCode] != 200) {
  //  NSLog(@"http error");
  //  return;
  //}

  // decode json
  NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
  if (!dict || ![dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSLog(@"error parsing json");
    return;
  }

  // now drop back to the main thread and do whatever with your dictionary
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"%@", dict);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I need to use costume HTTP headers, so I have to use NSURLConnection. I had edited my question